# How can I generate a TAGS file for Groovy classes for use in VIM/Emacs

Tags: vim, emacs, groovy, ctags

Exuberant cTags doesn't support Groovy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create a ctags config file and put it in your home directory.  Here is one that I use for actionscript(don't remember where I found it).  Look at http://ctags.sourceforge.net/ctags.html and see langdef, langmap, and regex options for more info.

ctags.cnf

```
--langdef=actionscript
--langmap=actionscript:.as
--regex-actionscript=/^[ \t]*[(private|public) ( \t)]*function[ \t]+([A-Za-z0-9_]+)[ \t]*\(/\1/f,function,functions/
--regex-actionscript=/^[ \t]*public function (set|get)[ \t]+([A-Za-z0-9_]+)[ \t]*\(/\1 \2/p,property,properties/
--regex-actionscript=/^[ \t]*private var[ \t]+([A-Za-z0-9_]+)[ \t]*/\1/v,private,private variables/
--regex-actionscript=/^[ \t]*public var[ \t]+([A-Za-z0-9_]+)[ \t]*/\1/u,public,public variables/
--regex-actionscript=/.*\.prototype \.([A-Za-z0-9 ]+)=([ \t]?)function( [ \t]?)*\(/\1/f,prototype,prototype functions/
--regex-actionscript=/^[ \t]*class[ \t]+([A-Za-z0-9_]+)[ \t]*/\1/c,class,classes/
```

Also if you use the TList Plugin I have this in my vimcrc

```
let tlist_actionscript_settings = 'actionscript;c:class;f:method;p:property;v:private variables;x:variables;u:public variables'
```

Comment: I was asking so I could use it with the TList plugin myself.

Thanks a lot.